# How do you properly nest for loops inside if/else statements in shell script?

Tags: sh

I have the following code in Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter a number:"; read n;
if (($# != 0)) 
    for ((i=1; i< $n+1; i++)) 
    do
      echo $i
    done
else 
    for ((i=1; i<21; i++)) 
    do
      echo $i
    done
fi
```

As you can tell, I am trying to print the values from 1 to n. If no user input is given, I automatically print from 1 to 20. When I run this script, it says I have syntax error near unexpected token `else`. Can somebody please help, I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Your missing https://www.shellcheck.net/ which can also help you in the future.

Comment: "shell" is not a specified environment. Please tag this with the correct shell. Also, check the description of tags. The other two and not just not helpful, they are downright wrong.

Comment: `for (( ... ))` is a bashism. `/bin/sh` implementations are not guaranteed to support it.

Comment: It's also pretty rare these days to *need* `/bin/sh`. If you're trying to write Bash, use `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `then`. In addition, as others have mentioned, your implementation is bashism, so note the change to the first line.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a number:"; read n;
if (($# != 0)) 
then
    for ((i=1; i< $n+1; i++)) 
    do
      echo $i
    done
else 
    for ((i=1; i<21; i++)) 
    do
      echo $i
    done
fi
```

Comment: Even then, this code isn't compatible with POSIX sh; `for ((i=1; i<21; i++))` is a bashism.

Comment: Agreed. This was simply to fix the syntax error in his expected implementation

Comment: Maybe you should change your shebang to be `#!/bin/bash` then?

Answer (score 2):

A version of your code that actually works with all `/bin/sh` implementations might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter a number:"; read n;

if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
  i=0; while [ "$i" -lt $(( n + 1 )) ]; do
    echo "$i"
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
else
  i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 21 ]; do
    echo "$i"
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
fi
```

Note the `then`, needed for the `if` construct to be valid; the change from `if (( ... ))` to `if [ ... ]`; and the change to `for ((;;;))` to a `while` loop for counting.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `then`:

```
if (($# != 0)) ; then
```